# Parsing Variant File Names in C#

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

i am trying to make an Mp3 Name Organizer, but i have a problem. How can i parse file names like this and in vary names. All file names has not a place like "Miami-Usa" etc.

**My output format must [Artist Name - Set Name Set Number - Place - Date]**

Place is optional

Any idea ?

> 04-Gareth-Emery -
>   A-State-Of-Trance-500-Miami-Usa
>   2011-03-27.mp3
>
> 06-Armin-Van-Buuren -
>   A-State-Of-Trance-500-Miami-Usa
>   2011-03-27.mp3
>
> 05 Leon Bolier - A State Of Trance 500
>   Johannesburg South Africa
>   2011-03-19.mp3
>
> Armin Van Buuren - A State Of Sundays
>   027 2011.03.13.mp3
>
> Ferry-Corsten - Corstens-Countdown-199
>   2011-04-20.mp3
>
> Arty - Anjunabeats-Worldwide-215
>      2011-02-27.mp3

Comment: -1 Downvoted because bad explanation, he has more cases than "place is optional".

Comment: @Matías Fidemraizer There is 3 cases. i can't post the whole file list.

Comment: If you want good answer, good explanations are needed. I can't read your mind, sorry. Hope others would provide what you need :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simple solution. Truthfully, the easiest way is to get a cheap intern to do it manually.

If you are looking for a solution in code, you'll need the code to:

1. Determine what format the filename is in, based on rules you define. E.g. "Contains no - character, so it does not have artist, just title"
2. Use these rules to extract the relevant properties.

No matter how you do it, **you** need to define these rules. They won't magically appear from the computer. Yes, it is very difficult to get right and I would probably get someone to do it manually.

You can make the task easier if you can manually separate the files into large groups of similar filenames that you can parse with a smaller rule set. You'll need to do this anyway, because some things are going to have conflicting rules (e.g. some files might have "artist-title", others "title-artist" - there is no way the computer will understand which is which).